# Create a repository on live code

Tags: git

I have a remote `ssh` server with a live website.

My home directory contains files and folders:

```
~/index.php
~/images/*
~/classes/*.php
~/tmp/*
~/.profile
```

I don't have access to the parent directory.

- How can I create a `git` repository on this existing code ? (With only actual code not `.profile` or `tmp` files for example).
- How to checkout the website on my local computer and commit directly into the live website ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place the files in the current directory under version control run `git init .`   (The `.` means "current directory" in Unix)

However, if you want to exclude certain files from version control, create a file, [.gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) (don't forget the leading dot) and place in it the files you want to exclude, one per line.  You can use wild cards:

> .*profile*
>
> tmp/
>
> etc/*.bin

create this file *before* you initialize the repository, and it is not a bad idea to keep the .gitignore file in version control itself.

As to how to work with your files remotely, git has a [number of options](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) depending on your workflow.

Comment: Thank you. OK so now I have the ignored files and the git repo initialized. Is it now under version control already?

Comment: next step is to type `git status` to see what you did, then `git commit` to commit your files to the repository.   This might help:
http://alistapart.com/article/get-started-with-git

Comment: I used git plugin for eclipse and it made my life easier. I used the command lines on the server. Thank you!

Comment: @MajidL To each his own; Eclipse gives me the hives, but Magit on Emacs is magical.   And you are very welcome for the answer, and very welcome to git.

Comment: just a last question: i made local modifications and tried to push them to the server and it got refused. Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Usually the reason why git would reject a push is if there was a conflict with the code on the remote repository.   The other alternative would be a misconfiguration of either the local or remote.   Try pushing in a terminal, you may get more informative errors than through the Eclipse plug-in.

Comment: I just asked another question, if you could take a look at it. Thanks :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161736/cannot-push-content-to-remote-repository

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69635/discussion-between-dmitri-and-majid-l).