# Cannot push content to remote repository

Tags: eclipse, git

I have a live http server.

I created a repository on the server home repository:

```
~ > git init .
~ > git add index.php
~ > git add files
~ > git commit
```

I checked out the files into my local machine using eclipse.
The files are all in my local machine and are under version control in Eclipse.

When I try to commit my modifications ("commit and push") I get the following error:

```
master:master [rejected - non-fast-forward]
```

Any idea why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I notice you initialized a non-bare repo on the server.  Normally, git will prevent you from pushing to a non-bare repo like that.  Can you try without Eclipse and see if your error changes?

Comment: On the server:  
'git init --bare .'  (including the dot but not the quotes)

Comment: initializing was not the problem. I successfully initialized locally and remotly. Now when I want to commit changes that it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try without eclipse?  That is, do this on the server in a new directory:  git init --bare .  and then this on the client machine:  git clone <remote repo URL>  Then add a file, commit it and push it to the server.  Copy and paste all your commands and the result.

Comment: `do this on the server in a new directory` can't I do this on the current directory? because that's where my live server points to

Answer (score 0):

Well I created two folders in my home repository:

```
~/live
~/repo
```

And now the commits and push work are fine.

Comment: Why?  I don't understand why this has anything to do with your repo.  There's something you're not saying.  :-)  It's OK glad it's working.

Comment: I have no idea either.
Maybe the fact that my repo and live were the same directory. Or something to do with bare/non-bare. :-/